# WebHDFS giving error in Hortonworks

Tags: rest, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

While setting up history server and hive server, webHDFS is giving following error in REST API.

```
curl -sS -L -w '%{http_code}' -X PUT -T /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz 'http://ambari1.devcloud.247-inc.net:50070/webhdfs/v1/hdp/apps/2.3.4.0-3485/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&overwrite=True&permission=444'
```

> {"RemoteException":
>   {"exception":"IOException",
>   "javaClassName":"java.io.IOException",
>   "message":"Failed to find datanode, suggest to check cluster health."
>   }}403

Answer (score 0):

As user hdfs check the cluster status

`hdfs dfsadmin -report`

I had the same problem, the report showed that the datanodes were not online. In the end I had to add the nodes to the /etc/hosts file. In your case it might be another reason, the essential thing is that the datanodes have to be up and can be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with HDP2.5. Mapreduce report the same Error and Ambari shows 0/3 Datanodes alive even though it also shows all 3 Datanodes are started.

For me, the reason is DNS.

My machines have central DNS server, so at first, I did not add the ip/host pair in /etc/hosts file, after deployment, Mapreduce server failed to start.

Then I add all machines ip/host paris in /etc/hosts file on each machine, and restart HDFS. The problem is resolved.